# How can I build static Go binaries which use C

Tags: docker, go

I have a problem with building a Go code which uses C. The idea is to build a binary inside the docker container and then create a slim docker image with that binary. Everything works fine for services which don't contain C code. I can run binary inside docker containers or on the host machine. But I can't run binary with C code neither inside the container nor on the host machine. I always  encounter the following error: `No such file or directory`. I set the env variables CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64. Can someone please tell me where the issue is? Thanks.

**Dockerfile** for $IMAGE

```
FROM golang:1.13-alpine

ARG PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/ffmpeg/pkgconfig

RUN apk update \
&& apk add \
    git \
    ffmpeg-dev \
    gcc \
    libc-dev \
    pkgconfig \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN wget -O- -nv https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh | sh -s v1.24.0
```

**Command**

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/go/src/project -w /go/src/project/api \
--env CGO_ENABLED=1 --env GOOS=linux --env GOARCH=amd64 \
$IMAGE go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o ../bin/api/api
```

Comment: Do you have gcc in the container?You can try to run gcc in container by shell to test it.

Comment: Show your commands (and dockerfile) and actual errors.

Comment: @Marc I added dockerfile and command how I build a binary.

Comment: And the actual error?

Comment: @Marc when I try to run binary code ./api I got error `No such file or directory`